# If scroll is 100px then turn background into red. (Pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with scroll using if statements.

How can I fix it and any helpful tips will be much appreciated.

```js
if (window.scrollY == '100px') {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div> hi </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That code does not keep running. It runs once and stops. You need to bind an event and check as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen on `scroll` event first.
`window.scrollY` value is integer.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div> hi </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works when you `window.scrollY >== 100` with `window.scrollY >= 100`. Thank you

Comment: @MiahTayen Right my mistake, typo :>

Answer (score 0):

The condition needs to be `>= 100`, and you need to listen to the `scroll` event of the window.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows -

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }else{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div> hi </div>
```

In your code, you had written the condition to be `window.scrollY == 100px`, so it was not working. But once you modify the condition, the code will work as expected.

Also, the `else` statement or transition effect are not needed, just added them for nice effect.